# PGAdmin4 for Docker not showing query results

Tags: docker, pgadmin-4

I'm using [dpage/pgadmin4](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4).

All is working fine but when I submit a query the results can't be shown. This is for all servers, tables and databases I have.

The error is about I'm not connected to the server but I can see a message telling me the rows affected in the result set.

I can use all other functionalities like create database, connect server, see DDL, table properties, attributes, etc...

This is my container execution script:

```
docker run --name pgadmin --hostname=pgadmin \
--restart=always \
-e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@guesswho \
-e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=youcannotsee \
-p 36321:80 \
-v /srv/pgadmin/:/var/lib/pgadmin \
-d dpage/pgadmin4
```

[image]

Note: I have a shared folder ( `/srv/pgadmin/` ) with `root` permission.

**EDIT**
The only thing I can see in log file over and over again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/browser/__init__.py", line 510, in index
    response = urlreq.urlopen(url, data, 5)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network unreachable>
```

Comment: Can you check & post the error which is present in the pgadmin4.log file?

Comment: @MurtuzaZ please see my edit. Thanks. Even `Network unreachable` I can use any other functions normally.

Comment: Tried other 2 different Docker images and same error.